# Lock Table taking more time to execute update statement oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, locking, batch-processing

We have a batch process which reads the base tables and performs some aggregation and then update the tables with an modified flag.

We have an update statement which updates around 3million rows.As a part of the business requirement we need to have table-level lock on the table which we are updating.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 t1 SET PARAMETER1=(SELECT p1 from TABLE2 t2 where t1.ROW_ID=ROWIDTOCHAR(t2.ROW_ID)
```

The observation today we made is that, update statement with table level lock is taking 35 mins while without table level lock is taking 20 mins.

I am not able to ascertain this observation. Please help!

Cheers,
Dwarak

Comment: the statement you provided will be read consistent, so the table will update properly even if other activity is occurring simultaneously.  Can you elaborate on the business requirement that demands a table level lock?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot confirm this observation?  Or you cannot understand it?  What precise help do you want us to give you?

Comment: I want to understand this observation thereby confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody but your database could tell you the reason of your observation. You'll have to do an AWR report.

However, it's **not** quite possible that the `UPDATE` would run longer because the table had been locked before.

Answer (score 1):

Did you account for caching (both in the database and the filesystem) in your testing? Depending on what you did when, one statement might have run faster due to data already being in memory.